# Script that change twitter profile picture

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm using [twitter-lite library](https://github.com/draftbit/twitter-lite) and I want to update a Twi profile picture.

At the moment I'm trying this :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Twit = require('twitter-lite'); 

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         '',
  consumer_secret:      '',
  access_token:         '',
  access_token_secret:  ''
});

var image64str = fs.readFileSync('kitten.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'});

T.post('account/update_profile_image', { image: image64str }, function(err) {
  if(err) {console.error(err); return;}
  console.log('done');
});
```

But I get the following error :

*/Users/huyvunguyen/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:272
return Body.Promise.reject(new FetchError(`invalid json response body at ${_this2.url} reason: ${err.message}`, 'invalid-json'));
^
FetchError: invalid json response body at https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_image.json reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
at /Users/huyvunguyen/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:272:32
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
type: 'invalid-json'
}*

Anyone know how can I debug this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is causing the error. It occurred at my end, too.

But `twitter-api-client` works flawlessly for the same code. Maybe it is a library-specific error.

Besides, `.post` method in `twitter-lite` doesn't take a callback. More info [here](https://github.com/draftbit/twitter-lite#postendpoint-parameters).

Here's what you can use:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
const { TwitterClient } = require('twitter-api-client')

var image64str = fs.readFileSync('pic.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'});

client = new TwitterClient({
    apiKey: '',
    apiSecret: '',
    accessToken: '',
    accessTokenSecret: ''
})

client.accountsAndUsers.accountUpdateProfileImage({image: image64str}).catch(e=>console.log(e)).then(res => console.log(res))
```